# Is there any way to know if a program was created with VB, C# or Delphi?

Tags: programming-languages

Is there any way to know if a program was created with VB, C# or Delphi and the compiler version?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use some software like **DependencyWalker** and just see what DLLs they use.

.NET binaries are easy to figure out, And there are also software that deassemble them back to C#.NET , VB.NET or C++.NET code for you (whatever you desire)

You can't determine if a .NET binary is written in VB.NET or C#.NET since it is converted into **MSIL** (Microsoft Intermediate Language).

Also applications like resource explorer should tell you information about the binary.

If you're a little more specific, I can provide more.

Comment: This doesn't work for Delphi applications, for the most part, because it only loads the standard WinAPI dlls. (Unless the executable was built with runtime packages, which is Delphi's version of the MSVCRTL.)

Comment: Using a resource explorer (PE explorer) there are information about the build system. But as I mentioned, Some conceal it, Though its yet figurable through assembly code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

With Delphi applications, you can use a resource editor like [XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm). Each executable has an RC_DATA resource called DVCLAL that identifies it as a Delphi app (and contains info about the compiler version). If the app uses the VCL (is a Windows GUI application), you can also see other RC_DATA resources that represent the form file (DFM). You can also view VCL/RTL classes in the binary using a hex editor.

[Reflector](http://www.redgate.com) can show you if an app is C# or VB.NET.

DependencyWalker (linked by another answer) will show you if the app is loading the VB runtime, which would identify a VB Win32 application.

Comment: too technical for the questioner. But nice.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a tool like [`PEiD`](http://www.peid.info/) (unfortunately this project has been discontinued, but the application is still working).

> PEiD detects most common packers,
>   cryptors and **compilers** for PE files.
>   It can currently detect more than 600
>   different signatures in PE files.